# Largest prime gap under $2^{64}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, prime-gaps

Thanks to Tomás Oliveira e Silva's extensive calculations, it is known that the largest prime gap less than $4\cdot10^{18}\approx2^{61.8}$ is 1476. I'd like an upper bound for the largest prime gap less than $2^{64}$. I know it will be horrifically large, but I'm hoping that more can be done than the best I know:
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{2^{64}}{25\log^2(2^{64})}\right\rfloor=374946102691094
$$
due to [1]. As DanaJ suggested in the comments, this can be improved by a result of Axler [2]. In fact Büthe [3] improves on both for this range, reducing the bound to 672606194883.

Note: When I write "the largest prime gap less than $x$" I mean "the largest $q-p$ where $p$ and $q$ are consecutive primes and $p<x$".

[1] Pierre Dusart, [Estimates of Some Functions Over Primes without R.H.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) (2010)

[2] Christian Axler, [New bounds for the prime counting function π(x)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1780) (2014)

[3] Jan Büthe, [Estimating π(x) and related functions under partial RH assumptions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.7015) (2014)

Comment: according to [this](http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaplist.html), it seems to be 1550 (p = 18361375334787046697, found by Bertil Nyman in 2014).

Comment: @achillehui: Nice find! But I'm looking for an upper bound, not a lower bound.

Comment: The difference between the upper and lower bounds on the nth prime at Pi(2^64) is a little lower than that limit, when using Axler 2013.  About half as much, but still "horrifically large".  There's got to be a better way using a maximum of the merit function, but I just see conjectures, e.g. Cramer's conjecture.  Excellent question!

Comment: Not an upper bound, but interesting:  From http://www.trnicely.net/gaps/gaps.html#Addendum we could use the Wolf model and expect the maximal gap to be ~1640, and Rodriguez's model to get 1646.  Given current data these seem not unreasonable.  But of course they're *not* an upper bound, just conjectured models of maximal gap estimates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new computations by [Prime Gap Search project (Mersenne forum)](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=23513&page=7) it seems we now have the exact answer: the largest prime gap below $2^{64}$ has the size 1550. This gap follows the 20-digit prime $$p=18361375334787046697.$$ We have $\log_2 p \approx63.9933$.

See also T.R.Nicely's page [First Occurrence Prime Gaps](https://faculty.lynchburg.edu/%7Enicely/gaps/gaplist.html#MainTable).

Comment: If the question was 'How much larger will be the next maximal prime gap to the current maximal ?' then the upper bound would be 3100 with this 1550 gap by the Ramanujan prime corollary and definition of maximal prime gap.

Comment: With the passing of T.R.Nicely, here is a link update https://faculty.lynchburg.edu/~nicely/gaps/gaplist.html

Comment: So just making sure, this implies that for all primes $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$ less than $2^{64}$ we know that $p_{i+1} - p_i < 1551$?

Answer (score 2):

A better upper bound is $10^9$. Starting at 1 (or $4\cdot10^{18}$, skipping the region checked by Oliveira e Silva's code), repeatedly add $10^9$ and find the previous prime. (I search for a probable prime and then prove primality with [APR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adleman%E2%80%93Pomerance%E2%80%93Rumely_primality_test).) Repeat until you get a number in excess of the desired $2^{64}.$

The process might start: $1 \to 999999937 \to 1999999927 \to \cdots.$

I performed this check in parallel with a total of roughly 100 core-hours.

This could be extended to a smaller bound ($10^8$ with $10\times$ the effort, $10^7$ with $100\times$ the effort, etc.) if desired. Of course if you try with a number smaller than the largest gap in the region the program would loop forever (though it's not hard to check for this situation).

At some point it would just be more efficient to sieve the whole interval and get exact answers. Naively extrapolating [Oliveira e Silva's Goldbach timings](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach.html) this would take about 2824 core-years, or about as long as a bound of length 4000. Since computers have gotten faster (albeit not much!) in the last four years, and since exact answers are much better, I certainly wouldn't recommend going lower than $10^4.$ I think even $10^6$ ($\approx$ 11 core-years) would take more effort than it's worth, unless you have access to serious computing power.

Comment: I used my code to do this with $10^8$.  157 hours single core serial.  With a good home computer running in parallel, $10^7$ could be done in a week.  [This comment was meant to note progress to 10^7, verification with completely different code.  I agree with your last paragraph even if numbers change slightly (primesieve on Xeons is faster, but only by 2x or so)]

Comment: @DanaJ Feel free to post 10^8 (or 10^7, if you do that!) as an answer!